# Remove _thumbnail_id from all custom post type

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to remove the _thumbnail_id meta key data from a custom post type in my wordpress database. I found this code which will allow me to remove it from everything, but I don't want it to remove it from my posts, just my custom post type called "svg" would anyone be able to help me adjust the code to do so?

```
global $wpdb;

 $attachments = $wpdb->get_results( "
 SELECT * 
 FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
 WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
 " );

foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->meta_value, true );
}

$wpdb->query( "
DELETE FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
" );
```

Or if you guys know a better way to remove the _thumbnail metakey from just SVG posts let me know as I have over 400+ svg posts and can't go through each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
DELETE m
  FROM wp_postmeta m JOIN wp_posts
    ON m.post_id = p.id
 WHERE p.post_type = 'svg'
   AND meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
```

**Note:** before you try to delete anything make sure that you have solid backup of your database just in case.

Comment: Thank you, where exactly would I be adding this to? My functions page?

Comment: If it is a one-time thing then just in any mysql client: mysql, phpMyAdmin, SequelPro,... what have you.

Comment: I get the error "Table 'shokzgui_GuideWP.postmeta' doesn't exist" when i try to run that in the Query of SequelPro also the postmeta table is called wp_postmeta so do i change anything or is that right?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. Corrected the answer.

Comment: Yes it did thank you very much, there was an error but i was able to update it. I believe it.

Answer (score 0):

First , your code will first delete all attachments ,and then clean (not only clean the `_thumbnail_id` ) -

Anyhow , in general lines , something like this should work :

```
SELECT FROM 'wp_posts', WHERE 'post_type' = 'my_post_type'
  INNER JOIN 'wp_postmeta' ON 'wp_post.post_id' = 'wp_postmeta.post_id'
  AND 'meta_key'='my_meta_key' 
 //  AND 'meta_value'= my_value'// this line only if needed ...
```

1. - BACKUP YOUR DATABASE .
     I take no responsibility for such an action.
2. - Change `SELECT` with `DELETE` after verification...
3. - The last line is only for demonstration, in your case I assume you do not need it - so delete accordingly ..